# Overloading equality F# operator on a discriminated union with tuple gives an unexpected result

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, operator-overloading, equality

Ok, so to make the complicated title more clear: I have a single-case union that's a generic tuple. The type also overloads the equality operator with the intent on making something like `Edge (1, 2)` equivalent to `Edge (2, 1)`.

```
type Edge<'a> = Edge of 'a * 'a
    with
        static member (=) (e1: Edge<_>, e2: Edge<_>) =
            match e1, e2 with
            | Edge(a,b), Edge(c,d) ->
                (a = c && b = d) || (a = d && b = c)
```

However, when I go to make two values of the Edge type that should be equivalent and compare them, it returns false.

```
> let e1 = Edge (1,2);;

val e1 : Edge<int> = Edge (1,2)

> let e2 = Edge (2,1);;

val e2 : Edge<int> = Edge (2,1)

> e1 = e2;;

val it : bool = false
```

I'm at a loss as to what's actually happening here. Is there something in particular about the equality (=) operator that makes it more complex to override than other operators?

Comment: It's worth noting that that's an absolutely terrible `GetHashCode` implementation, since any time `a = b`, it will return `0`.

Comment: @ildjarn this is quite some time later that I came back to this question, but you're correct on that remark. I've removed that chunk of my code sample to avoid anyone blindly copying and pasting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there was a hint in the error message (which you didn't post)

> warning FS0086: The name '(=)' should not be used as a member name. 
>      To define equality semantics for a type, override the 'Object.Equals' member. 
>      If defining a static member for use from other CLI languages then use the name 'op_Equality' instead.

You can actually check by adding `printf` calls in your original code and you will find that it is actually never called.

So then you try this:

```
type Edge<'a> = Edge of 'a * 'a
     with
         override x.Equals (y: obj ) =
             match  y with
             | :? Edge<'a> as e ->
                 match x,e with
                 |Edge(a,b),Edge(c,d)->(a = c && b = d) || (a = d && b = c)
             | _ -> false
```

which also fails.  The compiler error messages then walk you through a few more error messages until you get to

```
[<CustomEquality;NoComparison>]
type Edge<'a when 'a:equality> = Edge of 'a * 'a
    with
        override x.Equals (y: obj ) =
            match  y with
            | :? Edge<'a> as e ->
                match x,e with
                |Edge(a,b),Edge(c,d)->(a = c && b = d) || (a = d && b = c)
            | _ -> false
```

which works just fine.  The equals function is a little more complex than many of the other operators, so overriding it takes a little more effort.

Comment: Thanks John. I subsequently followed that rabbit trail after posting the question and almost got there, but your answer brought me to the working conclusion!